# Do Hindu scriptures acknowledge the presence of Dinosaurs?

Tags: scripture

Do Hindu scriptures acknowledge the presence of Dinosaurs?

Comment: I heard that the comet which was reason of extinction of dinosaurs is actually avatar of lord Vishnu i.e _Varaha_ avatar. There is a mention in scriptures that they fall on earth with glazing fire which produced a big atomic blast. but I don't have much info about it.

Comment: @KharoBangdo this link will be useful as it contains about dinosaur and other creatures described in our Hinduism https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8003/earth-era-description-in-hindu-mythology

Comment: Do Hindu scriptures acknowledge the extinction of Dinosaurs? Do Hindu scriptures acknowledge bacteria and viruses cause various diseases? Do Hindu scriptures foretell the invention of cellphones, internet and astronauts landing on the moon?

Comment: I really don't hope that people will say this question is on-topic and reopen now. It is still off-topic after the edit by user9392.

Answer (score 9):

In any case, we do find a reference to what easily could be understood to be dinosaurs in Srimad Bhagavatam when demons and demigods rode strange creatures into battle.

> grdhraih kankair bakair anye syena-bhasais timingilaih
>   sarabhair mahisaih khadgair go-vrsair gavayarunaih
>   sivabhir akhubhih kecit krkalasaih sasair naraih
>   bastair eke krsna-sarair hamsair anye ca sukaraih
>   anye jala-sthala-khagaih sattvair vikrta-vigrahaih
>   senayor ubhayo rajan vivisus te ’grato ’gratah
>
> “O King, some soldiers fought on the backs of vultures, eagles, ducks, hawks and bhasa birds. Some fought on the backs of timingilas, which can devour huge whales, some on the backs of sarabhas, and some on buffalo, rhinoceroses, cows, bulls, gavaya [jungle cows] and arunas. Others fought on the backs of jackals, rats, krkalasa, rabbits, human beings, goats, black deer, swans and boars. In this way, mounted on animals of the water, land and sky, including animals with deformed bodies [vikrta-vigraha], both armies faced each other and went forward.” (Bhag. 8.10.10-12 – The Battle Between the Demigods and the Demons)

Here we find a fantastical description of the vahanas used in a great battle in horary antiquity, but some of the creatures described have no English or Indo-Aryan equivalent such as bhasa, sarabhas, timingila, gavaya, arunas, krkalasa and vikrta-vigraha. So what are these creatures and why do they have no equivalent names in modern languages? Could they be extinct? Could any of these have been what we now call dinosaurs? We think so. The mere fact that the timingila is mentioned is proof enough that some of these creatures are going to be formidable predators – which ones?

Vikrta-vigraha translates as ‘animals with deformed bodies’ and krkalasa translates as ‘big lizard’. So when one’s opponent is riding a vicious animal like a rhinoceros or a timingila — then is riding an ordinary lizard into battle a good idea, even a big one? Krkalasa is a ‘big lizard’ — think dinosaur! And vikrta-vigraha are ‘animals with deformed bodies’ — think dinosaur! In any case, no vahana mentioned here could have been ordinary, – even the human vahanas must have been giants. So it is intelligent to think that if one takes these narratives to be true in the first place, then what we think of today as dinosaurs could surely be among the vahanas mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam.

The gavaya mentioned in the above verse translates as ‘jungle cow’ and interestingly enough these ‘jungle cows’ (also known in modern Hindi as nila-gaya, blue cows) still exist in and around Vrndavana, India and, like the Makara, they have the distinct characteristic of three animals — a cow, a horse and a deer. Once seeing these strange animals there is no argument that they are a ’three in one’ creature. So why not a Makara with a mouth of a crocodile, a body of a fish, and a tail of a peacock? You just haven’t seen one yet. But it looks like the archaeologists in England are on to something with their recent discovery of the Pliosaur.

It is true that the krkalasa and bhasa are not easily equated with Tyrannosaurus Rex and Pterodactyl, but then again, why not? It seems to be a matter of putting one and one together and moving on.

Yes – there were dinosaurs mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam and possibly other places in the vast Vedic literature. Unfortunately, it has been the thinking of some theists that the scientists have falsified dinosaur remains (“The Devil put them there”) simply to give credit to the evolutionary theory. But I think it is safe to say that such does not stand against the repeated discoveries of dinosaurs in different parts of the world and even in India.

Source: [srimad bhagavatam](http://gosai.com/writings/makara-myth-or-fact-dinosaurs-in-srimad-bhagavatam)

Comment: ‘animals with deformed bodies’ — think dinosaur!

Comment: It is true that the krkalasa and bhasa are not easily equated with Tyrannosaurus Rex and Pterodactyl, but then again, why not?

Comment: but in that case, why there has not been a single human bone/fossil found which dates back to "Jurassic period" ? No paintings, No tools ?

Comment: Zactly. I agree w/ this answer. I think these type of stuffs all existed in previous yug and chaturyug without a doubt.

Comment: @Ritwik If the humans in the Jurassic period were subjected to cremation by fire, it will be impossible to find any skeletal remains from the era. Burial is a very recent phenomena as is explained in Mahabharata which was started by the children of Turvasu after being cursed by Yayati.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 incorrect. Children were always buried. Rigveda mentions burial practices. Moreover, where are the paintings? rock edicts? ornaments? diamonds? Not even a single one has been found from dino era.

Comment: @Ritwik Cite mantras or else it is fake.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 I haven't read Rigveda completely. But the other argument stands still. Where are the paintings? rock edicts? ornaments? diamonds? all these things have a long life

Answer (score 2):

The subtext of this question is finding scientific evidence in religion or mythology.

One of the fundamental mistakes in understanding a religion is confusing mythology and science and attempting to find scientific evidence in mythology. Science is a set of working hypotheses based on facts tested and proven at that point in time. Mythology on the other hand should be treated like poetry and should not be confused with empirical science. In other words, one should not attempt to find factualism and historicity in mythology.

Whether a dinosaur or a dinosaur like creature appears in Hindu mythology is moot. The symbol and the meaning that the mythic image evokes in its context to an individual is what is important.

The question the extinction of dinosaur is a scientific one and there is a lot of information out there. Here is a link from Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event

Comment: So your position is that Hinduism is mythology?

Answer (score 1):

> [Yali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yali_%28mythology%29) is a mythical creature seen in many Hindu temples, often sculpted
>   onto the pillars. It may be portrayed as part lion, part elephant and
>   part horse, and in similar shapes. Also, it has been sometimes
>   described as a leogryph (part lion and part griffin), with some
>   bird-like features.

If you look closely at the statue Yali will have an Elephant below it.
we can assume that the sculptor compared the size of the elephant with the Yali, 
Now you get the idea how big Yali is.

Comment: How is that a dinosaur? The OP mentioned the word dinosaur not random big mythological creature.

Comment: But the point is that very big things like that existed, were here.