# Earth era description in Hindu mythology

Tags: vedas, scripture, yuga

Does any Hindu mythology has spoken about existence of ice age or dinosaurs or any other nature related historical stage? As per [Yugas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga), is there any reference of proof available to cite that these events happened on which era as per [timeline of evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_evolutionary_history_of_life)?

Comment: refer this  for your question : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/what-is-the-story-of-sharaba/2479#2479  in this link mention that dragon type animal exist

Comment: this also use ful :http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/rishi-converts-poor-dog-to-lion-and-then-to-dragon-which-tries-to-eat-the-rishi

Comment: Good question. I wanted to ask this. But in this site scientific explanations are banned. And unfortunately, in available scriptures there is not much science discussed. The concept & timelines of Yugas should be taken with grain of salt. They are too unrealistic to be sensible. It simply ignores all the Jurrasic/ice age, cavemen, Homo-X theories. @BhavinPatel, your answers don't discuss about the scientific historical stages.

Comment: Yugas are spoken of in the Puranas, there is no mention of yugas in the Vedas. So it's up to you if you want to accept them or not as true or allegorical. Patanjali speaks of evolution in his Yoga Aphorisms. Do a search on 'Patanjali' on this website.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Does Patanjali speak of spiritual evolution, i.e. the same atma attaining births as higher and higher animals, or does he speak of biological evolution, where the descendants of one animal are some other animal?

Comment: @iammind I think Bhavin's links were meant to address the dinosaur part of the question, not the historical stages part.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan See http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/153/how-is-evolution-portrayed/7677#7677

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ANIMALS :**

**ANCIENT SUPER HAWK :**

In [Srimad Bhagavatam](http://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/5/23/3) it is said that there were gaint hawks named **syena** or **zyena** that were able to **Catch and eat Elephants**.

**DINOSAURS :**

- The cowherd boys says a **Giant Lizard** resembling a **hill** and was lifted by lord krishna by his hand as in this [link](http://vanisource.org/wiki/SB_10.64.3)
- There are stones with **Dinosaurs and Humans Co-existence** in this [Link](http://www.mallstuffs.com/Blogs/BlogDetails.aspx?BlogId=321&BlogType=Spiritual&Topic=Dinosaurs%20in%20ancient%20hinduism%20scriptures)

**ANCIENT SEA MONSTER :**

- There is an ancient sea monster known as [**Makara**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makara_(Hindu_mythology)) and  which is able to kill other larger whales and is vahana of goddess ganga and this Makara is called by Modern Scientists as [**Plesiosauria**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesiosauria) they found that these kinds of reptiles existed before millions of years.

**HISTORY EVIDENCE :**
**MAHABHARATHA** :

- In rajasthan there is a [place](http://beforeitsnews.com/alternative/2010/10/ancient-city-in-india-irradiated-by-atomic-blast-debunked-201540.html) with hindu stone carvings which is **12000** years old and is radioactive because it is destroyed by a energy equal to our modern atom bomb.
  .

**RAMAYANA :**

- Lord rams bridge was found in between rameshwaram (TAMILNADU DISTRICT) and sri lanka it was confirmed by **NASA** that it is 1.7 Million years old in this [link](http://www.rense.com/general30/nasa.htm) and this [link](http://m.dailyhunt.in/news/india/english/the+new+indian+express-epaper-newexpress/the+ghost+town-newsid-57510894)

Comment: According to Shreemad Bhagavatam Vritrasura was  a demon or evil purusha , not a dragon but  there are two versions of the story one is Vedic story and one is puranic.

Comment: Lord's Ram bridge formed 500-600 years ago? It is million years old. Please cite directly from scriptures than from Wikipedia. You can edit the sentence and directly quote from Bhagavatam from [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/64/3).

Comment: @SreeCharan i changed it and how lord rams bridge is million years old i am not aware of it ?

Comment: Shreemad Bhagavatam is talking about HAWK not about  Giant eagles , the sanskrit  word  used for Hawk is "shayeNa"  in 5.23.3

Comment: @SwiftPushkar  These planets float in the air within the vast sky, just as clouds with hundreds of tons of water float in the air or as the great śyena EAGLES, due to the results of past activities, fly high in the sky and have no chance of falling to the ground.

Comment: @sakthi - yes , already seen that, but see this http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=hawk&script=&direction=ES&link=yes - see the last word :)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thank you i'll change it and do you know HOW lord rams bridge age to be million of years

Comment: @sakthi - No dont know the exact  answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51167/discussion-between-sakthi-and-swiftpushkar).

Comment: Good answer, thx ! :)