# Is scriptures talking about dinosour?

Tags: scripture

Many people are asking if hindu scriptures are true then why no explanation of dinosour given. As modern science has shown that dinosours exist before humans, do scriptures has any information regarding this.

Comment: Duplicates: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2428/21353
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8003/21353

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Hindu scriptures acknowledge the presence of Dinosaurs?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/do-hindu-scriptures-acknowledge-the-presence-of-dinosaurs)